# How to click and verify the existence of a pop up (alert)

Tags: python, selenium

I'm working with selenium.
while trying to click a button it creates a pop up (alert) and doesn’t return a page object.
Because of that I can’t use “click” alone as this method expects a page object and eventually fails because of a timeout.
I can use the “chooseOkOnNextConfirmation()” but this will click the pop up and i also want to  verify that the pop up actually appeared.
Is there any method that will click and verify this alert?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for an alert you will need to use either

getAlert() call which will click ok on the alert. It will return the text in the alert as well so you can check its the alert that you want.

so an example would be

```
self.assertEqual("An alert",selenium.get_alert());
```

Answer (score 2):

I am doing the following to dismiss an Alert (you can adapt to get it to only verify the popup)

```
def dismissAlert(): 
    result = None
    try:
        alert = browser.switch_to.alert
        alert.dismiss()
        result = True
    except NoAlertPresentException:    
        result = False

    return result
```

Answer (score 1):

as far as I know you have to use always in alerts

> selenium.get_confirmation()

from python doc:
If an confirmation is generated but you do not consume it with getConfirmation, the next Selenium action will fail.