# Interacting with alert/prompt popup window with python

Tags: python

I'm trying to test an application where a user enters information into a gui, clicks on save button and then has to click "ok" in an alert/prompt popup window for the request to take place to the web service.

I'm using a python script to automate the requests to the web service.

My question is:
after submitting the user information how can I interact with the alert/prompt popup to click the "ok" button so that the request completes. How is this being done within a python script.

I'm grateful for any input

Comment: Why you do not want to use browser based testing which is more realistic for functional testing(and other tests from users perspective)?

Answer (score 1):

If it is using web browser or any XHTML+ javascript based layout engine(webkit, KHTML, gecko), you can use [selenium](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/selenium)

[homepage](http://seleniumhq.org/)

[see also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3084850/how-to-click-and-verify-the-existence-of-a-pop-up-alert)

there are also others like

`windmill`

`twill`

and `pamie` for windows

I have used selenium which is pretty good.

Comment: @0xc00de, Thanks, I think I will switch over using selenium RC.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript is just a client-side thing. It doesn't matter what you select in the alert box. If you press Cancel, it won't happen but if you press OK, it will POST the form data.

You don't need to emulate a button press of OK. So, what really matters is to sniff the POST data. For that you can use Firebug (in Firefox) or Developer Tools (in Chrome) to sniff the POST parameters by using the Network tab.

Comment: I guess He needs to simulate users action for automated testing.

Comment: @ 0xc0de   That is right. I'm reading input information from a text file and pass it to the python script. In the original version, where no alert/prompt popup was used, the python script worked correctly, could send the request to the web service. Now, I need to figure out how I can interact with this alert/prompt popup within the same python script.

Comment: If at all possible I don't want to use selenium as this means I will have to spend quite some time figuring out how to set it up

Comment: Well can't help you in that case :(. I would suggest using browser automation as it provides realistic and reliable means of web testing.
I didn't face any problem with selenium, its pretty simple to install and use.